# Have no voltage to 2 downstairs GFCI receptacles and 3 upstairs. Breakers all show voltage leaving and none tripped

Tags: electrical

First let me say I am a commercial HVACR tech and not an electrician. I pulled all the non working receptacles and checked for 120v at the wire not the receptacle lugs. None have any power. I then went to the panel and checked all the breakers (even the double poll) for power and they all had voltage leaving. Somewhere in between I'm loosing voltage and want to know the easiest way to trace the wire to form a schematic of these circuits. I just bought the house and have no idea what feeding what or what circuit these are on. I'm sure this problem is an easy fix if I can just find what's feeding these circuits. I'm familiar with a multi meter and continuity checks so I anyone could just point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: If GFCI's are needlessly Daisy chained protecting each other, they must be reset in the order they appear on the circuit. (A GFCI without power feeding it won't reset.). I suspect you have a GFCI on that circuit you haven't found yet.   How this comes to be is someone says "crap this bathroom has no GFCI and installs one, when the bathroom was really already protected by a GFCI somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will check when I get home and post what I discover.

Comment: If that's the issue I'll write an official answer for you and include your options how to deal with it going forward.

Comment: If GFCI's are daisy-chained, you might as well remove all of them except the one closest to the service panel. One GFCI will protect all the GFCI's downstread from it.